Org mode export ignore [ / ] and [%]
In org mode, there's an export setting that disables the "TODO" keyword(s) from showing up in the result. That being:
#+OPTIONS: todo:nil 

However, let's say I have the following org header:
** TODO Example [1/2]
*** DONE A
*** TODO B

I want both the "TODO" keywords and the [1/2] to be removed from the export. Is there an option for that?
Thanks in advance

The setting is org-export-with-statistics-cookies: set it to nil and try exporting again (or use #+OPTIONS: stat:nil).
The doc string (C-h v org-export-with-statistics-cookies) says:

Non-nil means include statistics cookies in export.
This option can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword,
e.g. "stat:nil"

See also Export Settings in the manual.
In fact, there is a whole raft of such options that help you fine-tune the exported output. Use TAB expansion (C-h v org-export-with- TAB) to see them all:

29 possible completions:
org-export-with-archived-trees  org-export-with-author  org-export-with-broken-links
org-export-with-clocks  org-export-with-creator     org-export-with-date
org-export-with-drawers     org-export-with-email   org-export-with-emphasize
org-export-with-entities    org-export-with-fixed-width     org-export-with-footnotes
org-export-with-inlinetasks     org-export-with-latex   org-export-with-planning
org-export-with-priority    org-export-with-properties  org-export-with-section-numbers
org-export-with-smart-quotes    org-export-with-special-strings     org-export-with-statistics-cookies
org-export-with-sub-superscripts    org-export-with-tables  org-export-with-tags
org-export-with-tasks   org-export-with-timestamps  org-export-with-title
org-export-with-toc     org-export-with-todo-keywords

[Firefox mangles displays like the above, where TABs and SPACEs are intermingled, but I believe Chrome displays them correctly - (after checking) no, it does not - ah, well: do it in Emacs and you'll see).

Thank you very much NickD, helpful as always. The #+OPTION: stat was exactly what I was looking for.
